# Pan For Induction Heating

Tags: cookware

Is [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001KOUGU4) pan compatible for Induction Cooktop?

I understand it's asking about a particular product, but I figured, you guys would be really experienced to answer this based on your experience.

Comment: You should be able to edit a previous post using the small link under the tags, maybe you missed it. There is a row of light gray links, one of them should be "edit". If the other question was on-topic, I would have edited this addition into it for you. In this case, I closed the other question, as it was a question asking for us to recommend a model of equipment, which is off-topic. The new one is not off-topic, so I am leaving it separate.

Answer (score 3):

The production description doesn't mention it for some reason (maybe they think it is obvious), but this is a cast iron pan. Every cast iron pan, including this one, will work on an induction cooktop.

Many iron pans are not machined finely, so if you use cast iron on induction with glass surface (as are practically all modern induction heaters), you risk tiny scratches. I don't mind them and use a very similar pan, but if you want to keep your cooktop magazine-shiny, you should buy enameled or forged iron, or leave iron completely out and buy steel.

Answer (score 1):

Cast iron is in general a good choice for induction cooking, as it is a ferrous material.

Depending on what type of induction  cooktop (or burner or hob) you have, it may scratch the surface.  Some people just recommend slipping parchment paper under the pan to reduce scratching.

Comment: I am against paper use. It works for stews, etc. but most food for which I get out a cast iron pan need high temperatures, and the paper chars, stinks, and leaves (cleanable) residue. For long-and-slow cooking, there are better material choices than a raw-surface cast iron pot, and they tend to have a smooth surface.